# Update data.table by reference but populate only certain rows when duplicates are present using a prioritized vector

Tags: r, merge, data.table, conditional-statements, pass-by-reference

I didn't quite know how to word the title, but here is what I'm trying to do. I'd like to grow the data table `dt1` using columns from `dt2`. In `dt1`, there are duplicated data in the column I'm updating/merging by. My goal is to populate new columns in `dt1` at duplicates only if a condition is met 
specified by another variable. Let me demonstrate what I mean:

```
library(data.table)


dt1 <- data.table(common_var = c(rep("a", 3), rep("b", 2)),
                  condition_var = c("update1", rep(c("update2", "update3"), 2)),
                  other_var = 1:5)


dt2 <- data.table(common_var = c("a", "b", "C", "d"),
                  new_var1 = 11:14,
                  new_var2 = 21:24)

# What I want to obtain is the following
dt_goal <- data.table(common_var = dt1$common_var,
                      condition_var = dt1$condition_var,
                      other_var = dt1$other_var,
                      new_var1 = c(11, NA, NA, 12, NA),
                      new_var2 = c(21, NA, NA, 22, NA))
dt_goal
```

Updating by reference or merging populates all the matching rows (as expected), but this is not what I want:

```
# Updating by reference populates all the duplicate rows as expected
# (doesn't work for my purpose)
dt1[, names(dt2) := as.list(dt2[match(dt1$common_var, dt2$common_var),])]

# merging also populates duplicate rows as expected.
# dt3 <- merge(dt1, dt2, by="common_var")
```

I tried overriding the rows of merged `dt3` (or updated `dt1`) with `NA`s where I don't want to have data:

```
dt3 <- dt3[which(alldup(dt3$common_var) & dt3$condition_var %in% c("update2", "update3")), names(dt2)[2:3] := NA]
dt3
```

The logic in the code above finds duplicates `and` the unwanted conditional cases, and replaces the selected columns with `NA`. This partially works, with two problems:

1) If the value to keep (`update1`) isn't present in other duplicate rows (`b` in my example), they get erased too

2) This approach requires hard-coding the case I want to keep. In my real-world application, I will loop this type of data prep and the conditional values will change. I know the priority for updating the data table though:

```
order_to_populate_dups <- c("update1", "update2", "update3")
```

In other words, I want a code to grow the data table as follows:

1) When no duplicates, add columns by reference (or merge) normally

2) When duplicates are present under the `id` variable, look at `condition_var`

2a) If you see `update1` add data, if not, next

2b) If you see `update2` add data, if not, next

2c) If you see `update3` add data, if not, next, ...

I couldn't locate a solution for this problem in SO. Please let me know if this is somehow duplicate.

Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a typo in your definition of `new_var2`. should probably be `c(21, NA, NA, 22, NA)` instead of `21, NA, NA, 22, NA`

Comment: it seems difficult to understand from the example how the condition variable should work

Comment: Fixed the typo.  Sorry, I think what might have caused confusion was using `keep1` `keep2` etc. instead of `update1` `update2`. The order vector was supposed to match the values under the `condition_var` column.

Comment: Are you trying to update only the first occurrence of common_var?

Comment: If I could sort the data table in a custom way based on `condition_var`, updating the first occurrence should work per duplicate.

Comment: Just do a simple remap based on your condition before sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
cols <- paste0("new_var", 1:2)
remap <- c(update1=1, update2=2, update3=3)
dt1[, rp := remap[condition_var]]

setkey(dt1, common_var, rp)
dt1[rowid(common_var)==1L, (cols) := 
    dt2[.SD, on=.(common_var), mget(paste0("i.",cols))]
```

---

Explanation:
You can use `factor` or a vector to remap your character vector into something that can be ordered accordingly. Then use `setkey` to sort the data before performing an update join on the first row of each group of `common_var`.

Comment: I will test this as soon as I can, but can you please give me an idea of how this works? I'm still trying to get fluent in data.table.  Thanks!

Comment: Let see if this is what this is what you are looking for first

Comment: I tweaked your code a little bit (based on the updated post above (consistent naming of `keep` vs `update` under `condition_var`) and this seems to work:

`cols <- paste0("new_var", 1:2)`

`remap <- c(update1=1, update2=2, update3=3)`

`dt1[, rp := remap[condition_var]]`

`setkey(dt1, common_var, rp)`

`dt1[rowid(common_var)==1L, (cols) :=  dt2[.SD, on=.(common_var), mget(cols)]]`

Comment: Will add explanation later since it’s what u r looking for

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if i understood your example correctly or not. I can change the solution if needed.

```
# order dt1 by the common variable and 
setorder(dt1, common_var, condition_var) condition
# calculate row_id for each group (grouped by common_var)
dt1[, row_index := rowid(common_var)] 
# assume dt2 has only one row per common_var
dt2[, row_index := 1]

# left join on common_var and row_index, reorder columns.
dt3 <- dt2[dt1, on = c('common_var', 'row_index')][, list(common_var, condition_var, other_var, new_var1, new_var2)]
```

Comment: This is getting close (although I think there is a typo in the first line--`condition` at the end). Please read my comment on your comment above to clarify my question (also edited the post). I would still like to still specify the ordering of the `condition_var` column by using a character vector. The orders in real work application isn't alphabetical (e.g. the algorithm should apply a custom sorting to `condition_var` before indexing. Also, dt1 will have thousands of columns and dt2 will have hundreds. How can this be adapted so that we don't need to pass named variables as the list call?